# List of descendant ID - children, grandchildren etc

Tags: c#, linq, recursion

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Topic] (
    [Id]          SMALLINT      NOT NULL,
    [ParentId]    SMALLINT      NULL
);
```

I have a simple table (above) with a parent/child hierarchy. I'm using Entity Framework to extract the data. The number of rows is less than 100.

I want to get a list of descendant **ID**, consisting of the children, grandchildren and so on (possibly with the option of including the original root parent). As the table only contains a small number of rows, it's probably easier to extract all the data to a `List<Topic>` first and work on that, but I stand to be corrected.

The preferred output would be: `Dictionary<int, List<int>>`

*Where the key would be the ID and the list would contain child/grandchild ID's*

I've looked at tens and tens of solutions online but I can't find a solution that meets my needs. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is desired output? Some list of classes or list of classes with filled child collections?

Comment: Load all entries into a `Dictionary<int, List<Topic>>` using the `ParentId` as a key, then start from the id you want and keep resolving sub-topics from the dictionary until none exist

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Sorry, I don't understand what you mean from your message.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv In it's simplest form, a list of ID's would suffice which I could then use to get other required data. However, ideally a dictionary containing the Id, and a list of child/grandchild ID. It's better because this could then be made reusable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could populate a dictionary with the ParentId->Id relations and use that to resolve sub-topics:

```
// prepare dictionary
var dictionary = new Dictionary<short, List<Topic>>();

// in real life this would get replaced by your database query
var topics = new List<Topic>
{
    new Topic { Id = 1 },
    new Topic { Id = 2, ParentId = 1 },
    new Topic { Id = 3, ParentId = 1 },
    new Topic { Id = 4, ParentId = 1 },
    new Topic { Id = 5, ParentId = 1 },
    new Topic { Id = 6, ParentId = 2 },
    new Topic { Id = 7, ParentId = 2 },
    new Topic { Id = 8, ParentId = 3 },
    new Topic { Id = 9, ParentId = 4 },
    new Topic { Id = 10, ParentId = 4 },
    new Topic { Id = 11, ParentId = 8 },
    new Topic { Id = 12, ParentId = 8 }
};

// populate dictionary with relations from DB
foreach(var topic in topics)
{
    var key = topic.ParentId ?? -1;
    if(!dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        dictionary.Add(key, new List<Topic>());
    }

    dictionary[key].Add(topic);
}
```

Now that you have the mappings available, you can write a simple recursive iterator method to resolve the descendants of a given id:

```
IEnumerable<short> GetDescendantIDs(short from)
{
    if(dictionary.ContainsKey(from))
    {
        foreach(var topic in dictionary[from])
        {
            yield return topic.Id;
            foreach(var child in GetDescendants(topic.Id))
                yield return child;
        }
    }
}

// resolves to [1, 2, 6, 7, 3, 8, 11, 12, 4, 9, 10, 5]
var descendantsOfRoot = GetDescendantIDs(-1);

// resolves to [8, 11, 12]
var descendantsOfThree = GetDescendantIDs(3);
```

---

The `Topic` class used in the example above is just:

```
class Topic
{
    internal short Id { get; set; }
    internal short? ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be a good solution. I think it could be made even more efficient if the GetDescendantID's method was run over all entries (as a one off) and stored as a static dictionary itself. That way, no need to repeat the calls to build data each time.

Comment: @JohnOhara Assuming the list is static, yes, a single pass over the resulting dictionary would be sufficient to build the final one-to-many mapping :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider that result has to be stored in tree:

```cs
public class TopicModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId{ get; set; }
    public List<TopicModel> Children { get; set; };
}
```

Building tree:

```cs
// retrieveing from database
var plainResult = context.Topic
    .Select(t => new TopicModel 
    { 
        Id = x.Id
        ParentId = x.ParentId
    })
    .ToList();

var lookup = plainResult.Where(x => x.ParentId != null).ToLookup(x => x.ParentId);

foreach (c in plainResult)
{
    if (lookup.Contains(c.Id))
    {
        c.Children = lookup[c.Id].ToList();
    }
}

// here we have all root items with children intialized 
var rootItems = plainResult.Where(x => x.ParentId == null).ToList();
```

And searching for children:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<TopicModel> GetAllChildren(TopicModel model)
{
    if (model.Children != null)
    {
        foreach (var c in model.Children)
        {
            yield return c;

            foreach (sc in GetAllChildren(c))
                yield return sc;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this work for grandchildren as well as children?

Comment: Any nesting level

Comment: I'm having a few problems testing at the moment, perhaps you can help/advise. First thing is, I've has to change the "ContainsKey" to "Contains" as ContainsKey doesn't seem to exist. Now running, I iterate over plainResult but the output I'm getting for Children (with a string join) is the object name rather then the value "Pages.Topics.TopicModel"

Comment: How do I access the data in the finished list?

Comment: I do not understand question.

Comment: PlainResult will contain data that has been built using the above. If I then need to access it - say want to find all children of a certain ID - how do I do it?

Comment: It is simple recursive enumerator like in other answer.